# React Native Multiple Color Title in Navigation

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, reactjs, react-native

**I want to Implementing Navigator with Multiple color title** but it set only one color

[image]

How Set Multiple color title?

```
class Home extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

Home.navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Home',
    headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: MyConstants.colorNavbar,
    },
    headerTitleStyle: {
        color: 'white',
    },
    headerBackTitleStyle: {
        color: 'white',
    },
    headerTintColor: 'white',
};

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple, this is code:

```
<Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>
    I am bold
    <Text style={{color: 'red'}}>
        and red
    </Text>
</Text>
```

this is doc: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text.html

Answer (score 0):

Please find running code below

```
<Text style={{color: 'red'}}>
    Ho
    <Text style={{color: 'green'}}>
         me
    </Text>
</Text>
```